# Implementing a countdown timer that periodically syncs with backend in RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this requirement of displaying remaining time to users in one of our Angular components. Initial value for remaining time comes from server. It would be a trivial task using `interval` but due reasons we'd like to periodically resync the time with backend in case the browser stalled or something. I know this might not be totally necessary but I think this also as an interesting problem and would like to see it implemented.

The current code works just fine but is rather imperative using `setTimeout` recursively but I'm curious about getting this to work the RxJs way.

---

The thing works in a way that it counts down time correctly and also syncs with the server, but each time I sync there's a missed tick meaning time display on the UI skips a second until it shows correct time again. Has to do with starting the nested interval somehow or server request delay I suppose but can't find a cure.

```
const sync$ = this.http.get<number>(`/app/time/${this.hash}`); // this fetches the server time (seconds remaining)
const subject = new Subject<number>();

interval(this.syncInterval * 1000) // outer stream, runs every n seconds to sync with server
    .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        switchMap(() =>
            sync$.pipe(
                switchMap((timeLeft) =>
                    interval(1000).pipe( // nested stream for just downcounting the seconds betweeen syncs 
                        map((n) => timeLeft - n),
                        take(this.syncInterval),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
    .subscribe(this.subject);

// this goes to UI via async pipe
this.remainingTime$ = this.subject.pipe(map((n) => Duration.fromObject({ seconds: n }).toFormat('hh:mm:ss')));
```

Now it's just a small nuisance occasionally skipping a second on the UI but nevertheless I'd like to see it work. Also perhaps there's a more suitable pipeline for achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you might be looking for something like this:

```
import {
  map,
  interval,
  Subject,
  takeWhile,
  timer,
  tap,
  BehaviorSubject,
  switchMap,
  Observable,
  takeUntil,
  finalize,
} from 'rxjs';

function countRemainingTime(remainingTimeUpdater$: Observable<number>) {
  /**
   * seconds
   */
  let remainingTime: number;
  return remainingTimeUpdater$.pipe(
    switchMap((value) => {
      console.log('Setting new remaining time', value);
      remainingTime = value >= 0 ? value : 0;
      return timer(0, 1000);
    }),
    map(() => remainingTime--),
    takeWhile((value) => value >= 0)
  );
}

const remainingTimeComlete$ = new Subject<void>();

/**
 * seconds
 */
const remainingTimeUpdater$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1000);

const counter$ = countRemainingTime(remainingTimeUpdater$).pipe(
  finalize(() => {
    console.warn('Countdown completed!');
    remainingTimeComlete$.next();
  })
);
counter$.subscribe({
  next: console.log,
});

/**
 * Updating from the backend every 4 seconds
 */

interval(4000)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => /* we pretend to call the API */ timer(300)),
    tap((/* newValueFromBackend */) => {
      remainingTimeUpdater$.next(
        /* newValueFromBackend */ Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
      );
    }),
    finalize(() => console.warn('Updating from the backend completed!')),
    takeUntil(remainingTimeComlete$)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qtzdzp)

**And Angular version:** [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ypywje)